# How can I find memory leaks with profiler

Tags: android, memory-leaks, profiling, rx-java, rx-android

I already dumped tons of memory and figured out that there certainly are memory leaks. If you look at the screenshot, you will see that there is just one fragment, but 9 presenters of the same type. There should be only one. When I inspect one of the presenter instances, the profiler shows me the references to the presenter.
Those are all callback methods of RxAndroid methods. I am unsubscribing properly all of those in onDestroyView of the Fragment. Still the presenter instances are not cleaned up (as you can see).

So I am wondering how to distinguish valid (circular, internal) references, which just still exists because the object is still not garbage collected, and problematic references (which are causing the object not to be cleaned up).

Can somebody guide me on how to figure out where the memory leak might be found?

This dump was generated AFTER triggering the GC!
[image: android memory dump]

Comment: Did you try LeakCanary already ? 
https://github.com/square/leakcanary

Comment: I didn't look deeply enough into LeakCanary- will do so now...

Comment: Where do you store the `Subscription`s of those objects? Calling `unsubscribe` is not enough, you have to `null` out any references. Alternatively, use `onTerminateDetach`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try **[Leakcanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)** an open source library from Square to detect memory leaks. It saves you from doing lots of manual work like

- Taking hprof dump
- Analyse hprof dump to identify the leaks
- Find reference which causes leak
- Fix and repeat above steps

I have a blog of mine on memory leaks & Leakcanary, [you can find it here](https://medium.com/@akhilgupta.me/memory-leaks-in-android-fe4f5b97fa5e)

Comment: Leak Canary helped finding 2 leaks. But it didn't detect a third leak: I used the supportFragmentManager instead of childFragmentManager.

Answer (score 0):

If you force a garbage collection using the memory profiler then you know the additional unexpected objects you see there are in use so it's possible they are real leaks and are not just waiting to be collected.
You need to find the path to gc root, this will tell you the object which is keeping the others from being garbage collected.

Check out the '[Garbge Collection Roots](https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/)' section here for more info.
The Android memory profiler will tell you the shortest number of hops to get to the gc root but it may be better to just capture a hprof and use something like [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to see the path to gc root. Eclipse MAT can even check for leaks for you.